# ContentResolver for Dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox-api, android-contentresolver

This is what I tried.
(I am not using Dropbox API. )

I defined this filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And in my app:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
file_uri = intent.getData(); // Get a uri to the file that I double clicked on
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
file_is = cr.openInputStream(file_uri);
file_os = cr.openOutputStream(file_uri);
```

And now I just read and write this file as if it is a local file.

It works 90% of the times :-)
Occasionally, however, the file get reset and all data is gone :-(

Are Dropbox implementing contentprovider ?
If so - any pointer to a ContentResolver example?

If not, then I guess I must use Dropbox API
But then - how can I select a Dropbox file by double click?

Comment: "Are Dropbox implementing contentprovider ?" -- probably. "any pointer to a ContentResolver example?" -- you are already using `ContentResolver`. Your code works equally well for a `content` `Uri` as a `file` `Uri`. However, your `<intent-filter>` does not support the `content` scheme.

Comment: With <data android:scheme="content " /> my app was not listed when I double click on a Dropbox file. With <data android:scheme="file" /> my app is invoked on doubleclick and the strange thing is that file_uri.getScheme() returns "content" not "file" - I have no idea why.

Comment: You are welcome to have both `<data android:scheme="file" />` and `<data android:scheme="content" />` in the same `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: I did not solve it - not sure why my ContentResolver approach fail :-( Instead I worked around it. Dropbox allows a folder to be available offline. So once the dolder is on my phone storage, I use ES-file-manager to browse Dropbox local storage click on my file and ES calls my intent.